# Unable to start service Intent in my Android program, what's wrong?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-intent

I'm a newbie and just start to learn Google Android right now

So I learn some code after I googled, but I don't know why it can't run well as wished.
These program consists of two java files, AlarmService.java which contains an activity named AlarmService, and AlarmService_Service.java which contains a service named AlarmService_Service. Btw, I put it in the package com.AlarmService

Here where I created the intent in AlarmService activity (in AlarmService.java):

> Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmService.this, AlarmService_Service.class);
>
> mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(AlarmService.this, 0,intent, 0);
>
> Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start_alarm);
> button.setOnClickListener(mStartAlarmListener);

And the code in AlarmService_Service is quite long, but anyway I also made a Toast to prompt me a text to ensure if this service is functioning or not.

It looks like the program failed to load AlarmService_Service. Nothing happen when I clicked the button, not even the Toast, and I saw this message in LogCat:

> Unable to start service Intent {flg=0x4 cmp=com.AlarmService/.AlarmService_Service (has extras) }: not found

Honestly, I'm not familiar with Android so I keep wondering what is wrong with this code.
Did I miss something? Or is it because that it couldnot find AlarmService_Service.class?

Thank you for your big help.

Answer (score 2):

I am not too familiar with services (yet) but I can see that there is a `<service>` element in the Manifest.xml.
Have you declared your `AlarmService_Service` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

See more info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.AlarmService" android:versionCode="1"    android:versionName="1.0">

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".AlarmService" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter></activity><service android:name="AlarmService_Service"></service></application></manifest>

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get your PendingIntent the following way:

```
PendingIntent mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(AlarmService.this, 0, new Intent(AlarmService.this, AlarmService_Service.class), 0);
```

However see [this source for a working example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService.html)

Comment: Thank you.. The message didn't appear anymore.. :D..
Btw, do you know why I should not instantiate the Intent firstly, like my last code?